# Is this the correct use of "rule out"?

Tags: synonyms

I need to argue with this topic: "True success can be measured primarily in terms of the goals one sets for oneself"

Now I was wondering can I use the following quotation:

> Having a good goal toward a success is **ruled out** when a damaging measure is taken in reaching that  success.

I want to say:

> Having a good goal toward a success is **not a considerable matter** when a damaging measure is taken in reaching that success.

Comment: I can't tell what your intended meaning is well enough to say yes or no. The subject of your sentence is "Having a good goal toward a success", but I have no idea what that means. Do you mean succeeding at a goal? Setting a goal? How can a goal be put 'toward' a success?

Answer (score 2):

There's something very awkward about that usage.  One big issue is that you say "having a good goal...is ruled out" but what you mean is "using defined goals as a measure of success is ruled out".  Aside from not really saying what you mean, there's a temporal problem.  Goal setting happens first, then measures are taken.  So a measure that was taken can't rule out goal setting because it already happened.

My guess as to the source of the confusion is that it involves "considerable matter".  When something is ruled out, that means you no longer 'consider' pursuing or engaging in it.  It doesn't mean that it is no longer a concept to be taken into consideration for other purposes.

Side note, 'considerable matter' tends to read as 'a large or important thing or concept' rather than 'a concept worth considering' so that goal sentence is a little rough too.

Possible usage--mainly to show how 'ruled out' can work if its target (success metric, rather than goal setting) is clear.

> Self set goals are ruled out as measures of success when they result
>   in damaging measures being taken.